# How to run add_action() or add_filter() after a button click?

Tags: php, wordpress

I wrote a simple plugin to append some text to every post content by using add_filter(), which is working fine. but now i want to run the add_filter only after a button is clicked. so i but a button into my options page and added a function to execute after it is clicked. but the problem is when i put add_filter() inside that button action function, it won't execute. 
Can anyone help me with the code? thanks!

This is working as it is in the root of php file.

```
add_filter("the_content", "appendAction");

function appendAction($the_Post) {

   $the_Post.=" Bye ! ";

   return $the_Post;
}
```

but not working when put in a button action function

```
function test_button_action(){

   echo "button clicked "; //this runs after clicking button but not below code

   add_filter("the_content", "appendAction");

   function appendAction($the_Post) {

      $the_Post.=" Bye ! ";

      return $the_Post;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress does some naughty output buffering manipulation. Many times it's too late to reach the page on time before your changes reach the template that gets outputted. I'd suggest using a debug tool like xdebug, or writing to a log file to see if your breakpoints are being encountered. You can also do an echo and immediately follow it up with an exit to get around output buffering manipulation to see if your code is being ran. For example `echo 'reached this point in the code';exit;` If it's too late in your template, many times you'd need to have a new slot in your template that can read late information you'd want to insert on the page, then use JavaScript to put it in the proper spot on the page.

Get us some more information regarding the cause, and I can give a more detailed answer.

Comment: thanks, i'll check it. do you know how to do this ( execute add_action() after a button click ) in any other way?

Comment: @TharinduEranga A button is something that lives on the frontend. Can you be more clear what is happening what they click the button? How is it reaching the backend? Does this button submit a form? Is it actually a link that sends a querystring to the backend? Does it need to stay in session?  Or do you need it to pull something from the backend and append it to the page through Ajax such as going through Wordpress's [REST API](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/routes-and-endpoints/) with an endpoint beginning with `/wp-json/` ? Please explain.

Comment: yes a button will press and a form submits. it invokes the method i put in question.

Comment: @TharinduEranga Difficult to say without seeing where and how you're invoking `test_button_action`. It needs to be invoked as early as possible so `add_filter` can be applied before the content is already returned to the template for outputting. If you really have a submitting form, you should already know to call `test_button_action` immediately in your code as high as possible. Doubt it will make a difference, but you can try moving your function definition for `appendAction` outside of `test_button_action`. Only call `add_filter("the_content", "appendAction");` within `test_button_action`.

Comment: You should be able to include a hidden field on your form that you can have Wordpress listen for in order to know to call `add_filter("the_content", "appendAction");` as early as possible when the form is submit...  Where are you invoking `test_button_action`? Should be doing this from `functions.php` ...  
Also are you putting this in a theme or a plugin?